# Parse .xml file in a specific way

Tags: text-processing, xml

I have the following .xml and I want a specific output:

```
<ContactPerson>
<GivenName>John</GivenName>
<FamilyName>Wayne</FamilyName>
<PhoneFixList>
<PhoneFix>78787878</PhoneFix>
</PhoneFixList>
<EmailList>
<Email>john.wayne@gmail.com</Email>
</EmailList>
</ContactPerson>

<ContactPerson>
<GivenName>James</GivenName>
<FamilyName>Stewart</FamilyName>
<PhoneFixList>
<PhoneFix>90909090</PhoneFix>
</PhoneFixList>
<EmailList>
<Email>james.stewart@gmail.com</Email>
</EmailList>
</ContactPerson>
```

Output:

```
John Wayne  78787878  john.wayne@gmail.com
James Stewart  90909090  james.stewart@gmail.com
```

In some cases, I have more than two `<ContactPerson>` so I would be nice to have a great loop to resolve this. I've tried to resolve the problem with a for loop but I always have the result:

```
John Wayne  78787878  john.wayne@gmail.com
John Wayne  78787878  john.wayne@gmail.com
```

Comment: The XML is faulty. It has no root node and `<PhoneMobileList>` has no end tag.  This can not be parsed with an XML parser.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the following (modified) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <ContactPerson>
    <GivenName>John</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Wayne</FamilyName>
    <PhoneFixList>
      <PhoneFix>78787878</PhoneFix>
    </PhoneFixList>
    <EmailList>
      <Email>john.wayne@gmail.com</Email>
    </EmailList>
  </ContactPerson>
  <ContactPerson>
    <GivenName>James</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Stewart</FamilyName>
    <PhoneFixList>
      <PhoneFix>90909090</PhoneFix>
    </PhoneFixList>
    <EmailList>
      <Email>james.stewart@gmail.com</Email>
    </EmailList>
  </ContactPerson>
</root>
```

The [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)
invocation

```
xml sel -t -m '//ContactPerson' -v 'concat(GivenName, " ", FamilyName, " ", PhoneFixList/PhoneFix, " ", EmailList/Email)' -nl file.xml
```

produces

```
John Wayne 78787878 john.wayne@gmail.com
James Stewart 90909090 james.stewart@gmail.com
```

The invocation of XMLStarlet contains an implicit loop over all `ContactPerson` nodes, and for each of these, the specific fields are concatenated to produce the correct output.  The `-nl` at the end causes a newline to be printed.

Comment: Thank you Kusalananda. 
Is there any form to get the result without the xmlstarlet?

Comment: @lendoiro XMLStarlet in the command line XML parser that I know best. You could possibly do it by means of `sed` and/or `awk` as well, but these are generally not good tools for parsing XML, and I will not write an answer using them.

Comment: Ok. I was triying with `sed` and/or `awk` but I couldn't resolve it.
Thank you for your reply

Comment: Don't even try to process XML with tools that don't understand XML.

Comment: That last comment was probably for you @lendorio. I'm well aware of the issues with parsing XML using anything other than an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

With `xml2` (and a shell with support for the `$'...'` quotes):

```
{ echo "<r>"; cat file.xml; echo "</r>"; } |
  | xml2 | 2csv -d $'\t' ContactPerson GivenName FamilyName EmailList/Email
```

(for `ContactPerson`s with more than one email address, the last one is returned)

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with having a second file for processing this, you can make an XSLT file and use it to transform your XML file using `xsltproc`.

**phones.xsl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="ContactPerson">
  <xsl:value-of select="GivenName"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="FamilyName"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="PhoneFixList/PhoneFix">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:for-each select="EmailList/Email">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then transform the file (using @Kusalananda's XML as `phones.xml`):

```
$ xsltproc phones.xsl phones.xml
John Wayne 78787878 john.wayne@gmail.com
James Stewart 90909090 james.stewart@gmail.com
```

Using XSLT has the advantage that you can loop through repeating elements, do conditional output and so forth. If you're comfortable with a bit of study and programming, it's very powerful.